# Em.Computed.sort triggers computed property twice

Tags: ember.js

One of the components in my app contains an array that is copied, filtered, sorted, sliced and then finally looped through. I'm having problems with the `Em.computed.sort()` part which seems to trigger another computed property to run twice (which then causes a bunch of other issues in my app).

```
{{#each item in final}}
    <li>{{item.name}} -- {{item.age}}</li>
{{/each}}

<button {{action "changeModel"}}>change model</button>
```

.

```
// initial property copied
initial: function(){
    return this.get('model').slice()
}.property('model'),

// sorted
sortProp: ['age:desc'],
sorted: Ember.computed.sort('initial', 'sortProp'),

// slice it and then loop through it - this function runs twice
final:  function(){
    return this.get('sorted').slice(0, 5)
}.property('sorted.[]'),
```

I have a simplified version of my issue - [see my jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gejizuquku/1/edit?html,js,output).

Basically, when the model changes, the `final()` function runs twice - once containing the old model data, and a second time with the new, updated model data. During both times the initial data is correct, but `Em.computed.sort` is only updated with the new, correct data the second time `final()` runs.

Is there a way to avoid `final` being called twice?

Comment: @Kingpin2k Could you explain the reason behind the edit from `Ember.computed` to `.propery()`? I thought the former was preferable to the latter.

Comment: Only if you're writing a third party app or are disabling prototype extensions in your app (which you aren't based on the fact that you're using the prototypal approach on initial) .  The preferred way is the consistent way.  The prototypal way is the more common and likely to be understood by the masses.  You're welcome to change it back, but it'd make more sense to then define initial as such as well.

Comment: On another random note, this looks like a bug to me in `Ember.computed.sort`.

Comment: Ahh I see, I'll open a ticket on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you are not just adding/removing values to the `model` array, but are replacing it altogether. Therefore, perhaps `Ember.computed.sort` is not working for you as you expect it to.

The following seems to work

```
  sorted: function(){
    return this.get('initial').sortBy('age').reverse();    
  }.property('initial'),


  // slice it and then loop through it
  final: function(){
    console.log('FINAL ran', this.get('initial.length'), this.get('sorted.length'));

    return this.get('sorted').slice(0, 5)
  }.property('sorted'),
```

See the working jsbin [here](http://jsbin.com/joqetu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that Embers array computed support is very fragile and has a number of [issues](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/9462).

My recommendation is don't use them as they are unlikely to be fixed any time soon as computed array properties are just too complex to get right with the current approach in Ember.

Instead just use a regular property depending on 'model.@each.age' that slices the model array and returns a new sorted array.

If you look at the underlying array computed sort implementation in Ember you will see that the simple approach I describe behaves correctly and works efficiently compared to the daunting amount of code and state tracking in Ember.

If you are concerned with sort efficiency then I recommend using a tsort implementation as it is often O(n) for interactive changes as it exploits runs and partially sorted arrays.